# Where is the Intermediate Value Theorem Valid?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

I'm aware that $\mathbb{R}$ is not the only set that satisfies the least upper bound property, the $p$-adics do also. Does the intermediate value theorem also hold in the $p$-adics then?

What are the spaces where the intermediate value theorem hold?

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Generalizations). $p$-adic related topics can be found in chapter four of [this text](https://www.amazon.com/p-adic-Numbers-Introduction-Fernando-Gouvea/dp/3540629114).

Comment: You’re speaking of real-valued functions, it would seem. For real-valued functions of a $p$-adic variable, there is no intermediate-value theorem, ’cause the $p$-adics are not connected; in fact they’re totally disconnected, but that’s another story.

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate value theorem can be generalized for topological spaces.  For me, this makes sense, since the hypotheses for the IVT are in essence that given a function $f:X \to Y$, where $X,Y$ are topological spaces and

1. X is connected
2. $f$ is continuous
3. There is some ordering on $(Y,<)$ (equipped with the order topology)

then the intermediate value theorem holds.

We need hypothesis $1$ and $2$ to make sure that (heuristically at least) there are no "jumps" in the values our function takes. For example, $f:(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous, but its domain is disconnected,  so we cannot guarantee that the function takes on the value $0$. On the other hand take $f$ to be any step function on a connected domain, and note that it fails to satisfy the intermediate value theorem.

Hypothesis $3$ is there simply to make sense of the theorem anyway. Our IVT for $\mathbb R$ can be recovered by noting that the connected components of the real line are exactly the rays and intervals.

If I'm not mistaken, the $p$-adic rationals  are totally disconnected as noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644275/connected-components-of-p-adic-rationals), so it seems unlikely that there would exist a generalization to this setting.

Comment: I guess you’d need to know that the intervals of $Y$ were the only connected subspaces.

Comment: I believe this is covered in my penultimate paragraph, although if there is a way to clarify that point, I would be glad to (or are you making a different point altogether that I am ignorant to?)

Comment: Fine for $\Bbb R$, but I was thinking of your general statement, involving a target space $Y$ possibly more general than $\Bbb R$. (But I don’t know of any such $Y$ other than $\Bbb R$ ! )