# Generalization of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I searched for "intermediate value property" and "intermediate value theorem generalization" on this site and only found one link that seemed relevant, but it did not directly answer my question ([Where is the Intermediate Value Theorem Valid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069333/where-is-the-intermediate-value-theorem-valid/2069732#2069732)).

I am studying the book *Elementary Analysis* by Kenneth Ross (second edition). On page 135 he states the Intermediate Value Theorem in the calculus context, i.e. for a continuous function $f$ from an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$. On page 180 he states that a continuous function between two metric spaces preserves connectedness. Then he says, and I quote:

> Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on a metric space $(S, d)$. If $E$ is a connected subset of $S$, then $f(E)$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $f$ has the intermediate value property.

I understand why $f(E)$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. It's because $f$, being continuous, preserves connectedness. But what is the "intermediate value property" in this context? Typical statements of the IVT rely on some sort of ordering inherent to the domain of $f$, but $S$ does not necessarily have any notion of order (example: $S = \mathbb{R}^2$).

After a little bit of Googling, I was pointed to Theorem 24.3 (also called the Intermediate value theorem) on page 154 of *Topology* by James Munkres (second edition). I quote it below. Could this be what Ross is referring to?

> Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a continuous map, where $X$ is a connected space and $Y$ is an ordered set in the order topology. If $a$ and $b$ are two points of $X$ and if $r$ is a point of $Y$ lying between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there exists a point $c$ of $X$ such that $f(c) = r$.

For what it's worth the link I included above seems to support my suspicion.

Note that I am completely unfamiliar with topology, so any explanation of the generalized IVT is likely to go over my head; I am just hoping to confirm exactly what Ross is referring to when he mentions the "intermediate value property".

Thanks.

---

For completeness I will include the (abridged) statement of IVT from page 135 of Ross' book.

> Intermediate Value Theorem: If $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on an interval $I$, then $f$ has the intermediate value property on $I$: Whenever $a, b \in I, a < b$ and $y$ lies between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$... then there exists at least one $x$ in $(a, b)$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Generalizations

Comment: Not sure specifically what you're referring to there. The penultimate paragraph in that link looks like approximately the same as what I quoted from Munkres' book. Maybe that's the answer I'm looking for.